# How to post authorization request to the Ministra TV Platform 5.3.0 server

Tags: android, authentication, portal, iptv

all!
I am going to develop an Android stalker portal client app from scratch.
Actually, I want the app to be compatible with all stalker servers including Ministra, but at this early stage it is okay if it's compatible with Ministra 5.3 only.
The problem is that I can't find any document or guide that tells me how to post request for authentication to the server.

This is all I have so far researched, but it doesn't seems correct or maybe I don't know the meaning of each params.

POST; http://{base_url}​/auth​/token
Authorization request. Use OAuth2 password flow with additional parameters

Client identifier from table clients
(Example Value)

```
{
  "client_id": "client",
  "client_secret": "client_secret",
  "grant_type": "password",
  "username": "user",
  "hw_password": "This is needed field with empty value",
  "password": "password",
  "mac": 8698576271,
  "activation_code": "string",
  "meta_1": "Meta 1 for device. Please check with us what data you need to send. Required for get token request.",
  "meta_2": "Meta 1 for device. Please check with us what data you need to send. Required for get token request.",
  "meta_3": "Meta 1 for device. Please check with us what data you need to send. Required for get token request.",
  "refresh_token": "token"
}
```

Success response

(Example Value)

```
{
  "access_token": "token",
  "refresh_token": "refresh_token",
  "token_type": "password",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

default 
Error response with status code 200
(Example Value)

```
{
  "error": "Not supported access type",
  "code": "server_error",
  "error_description": "error message",
  "error_uri": "error description"
}
```

Can anyone teach me?